# Transform array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have values in my array as:

```
var chartData=[["web",0],["file",2],["desktop",2],["laptop",17]]
```

I need to convert this array into

```
var chartData= [["Web","file","desktop","laptop"],[0,2,2,17]]
```

How to write proper JavaScript function for this conversion.
So far I have used a for loop:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)

        {
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                chartData[i][j] = chartData[j][i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: gerado, yes I do have outer square bracket, also I have used for loopsfor (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                    chartData[i][j] = chartData[j][i];
                }
            }

Comment: @DeepshikhaSharma, have a look to my answer.

Comment: Create two new empty arrays. Loop through your original array and get each of its elements. Each element is itself an array of two elements. Push one of those elements onto one of your new arrays, and the other element onto the other new array. When done with this loop, create another new array with two elements, each element being one of the two new arrays you just created.

Comment: add your code to question not in comments

Answer (score 0):

Check it out

```js
const chartData = [["web",0],["file",2],["desktop",2],["laptop",17]];

function convert(array) {
  const length = array.reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b).length;
  const result = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result[i] = array.map(el => el[i]);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(convert(chartData));
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do :

```
var chartData=[["web",0],["file",2],["desktop",2],["laptop",17]];

var outData = [];var a1Out = [];var a2Out=[];
for(i=0;i<chartData.length;i++){
var a1 = chartData[i][0];     //first array value
var a2 = chartData[i][1];     // second array value
    //save them in seperate arrays
    a1Out.push(a1);     
    a2Out.push(a2);
}

outData.push(a1Out);
outData.push(a2Out);

console.log(outData); //final array
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls7cs2wm/)